# TFS GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

i have a strange problem with my TFS. I have a project in my machine without source control, than i created a  new collection in visualstudio.com to control my project and added it to source control,etc. When i try to make a checkin e get this error:

Multiple errors occurred during the operation, the first of which is displayed below. A full error list is available in the Output Window.

D:\Project\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I have no idea why its ocurring. It could be the .snk files that i have in this project?
Thanks for now.

Comment: Is your date/time set correctly? Are you using a proxy server or is Fiddler running?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Date/time is correct and no Fiddler is running.

Comment: I had similiar problem, I pretty much tried everything, but at the end; just changed the comment of the check-in to "WTF?!!!!!" and it worked nicely. Just try to change check-in comment content.

Comment: And by the way, your Visual Studio might require you to re-enter live credentials, but you need to do it manually. In VIsual Studio window, top-right corner should have your authentication details, make sure it's showing green, instead of orange.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a certificate issue from the box that is trying to connect.  Can you try installing the SSL certificate downloaded from the browser in the Trusted Root Authority of the machine that is trying to connect?